# Getting from Siem Reap (Cambodia) to South Laos and around for 2-3 days

Tags: car-rentals, laos

I am in Cambodia (Phnom Penh and Siem Reap) and would like to see a bit of Laos for 2-3 days. It seems the closest option is Pakse (Laos) and from there Wat Phu and Bolaven Plateau.

I am unclear about the following things:

1. How to get there? There is a bus but it takes very long. There is a flight from Siem Reap to Pakse but it is expensive (300$+). Is easy to get a rental car to drive from there to Laos or is it not recommended or even possible?
2. What is the best way to get around there? Does car rental work (US international drivers permit) work flawlessly?
3. Is there anything besides Wat Phu and Bolaven Plateau that I should not miss or consider instead in South Laos?

Comment: Have you thought about flying to Bangkok and then to Ubon Ratchathani?

Comment: No I have not. Could you elaborate? Do you mean as a way to get to Wat Phu or instead? I just looks like a more complex journey at the first glance